# Web Service in java using Eclipse IDE

Tags: android, mysql, web-services

I am new in Java Web Services.I am trying to develop a **web service in java using Eclipse IDE**.and then integrate it with my android application.
I have a form with some information of client in my android app,now what i want is, as client submit the form of android app that must hit the web service and web service gets the form data and save it into the MYSql Database in JSON Format.
Kindly give me some suggestions or link to do this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Apache CXF API is well versed in eclipse.  It provides support for both SOAP and REST type of Web Services.

Comment: Thanks but how to configure it with MAMP,can you please help me in this also??